# handle the eval function exceptions

Tags: python, eval

I'm using the eval method in my project and I have to handle all the possible exceptions it may raise. I thought that simple try and except would work but when I enter a symbol it doesn't familiar with it stuck.. like eval("5:2").

```
try:
    max = abs(eval(game_function))
except:
    while True:
        x += (x_f_coordinate - x_0_coordinate) / 1050
        try:
            max = abs(eval(game_function))
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                raise
        except:
            if x < x_f_coordinate:
                continue
```

It's freezing in the 7th line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you use the `eval()` method?

Comment: `5:2` isn't valid Python syntax. `eval` is throwing a syntax error... but you catch all exceptions, so it's hidden from you and the loop will never reach its stopping condition. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have a function and i'm trying to find the highest y value among two x coordinates, so i'm using eval to assign the x values and get their y. Its working when I enter a valid function but not when I enter something eval don't now what to do with... the condition must work if the 7th line weren't freezing.. I guess.. i just don't understand what is the KeyboardInterrupt that i get when i press ctrl-c in the cmd and why the exception deosn't catch it